# Property says it can't be read, even though it can read the property

Tags: javascript, angularjs, typescript

Before I start, I just want to say I have very little experience with javascript, so maybe I'm missing something very obvious, but anyways.

I have an array of objects called Accommodations. I have the following code:

```
alert(this.quoteService.activeBasket.components.length);
```

This alert shows a length of 3, but I get a ton of errors saying:

> An unexpected error has occurred. TypeError: Cannot read property 'length' of undefined

I'm just not sure how it's possible that it can read the .length property, but it's throwing errors that it can't...

Originally, the component object wasn't imported into this file, but even after importing it, I still have the same error...

Any help is greatly appreciated.

---

Edit:

Here is a little more context: 
Basically I have an html file that has a radio button, this button should be greyed out, based on the method found in the ng-disabled tag:

```
<li class="c-3-12">
    <div class="radio-btn" tl-field>
        <input type="radio" class="radio" ng-model="vm.requiredBookingState"
               ng-value="1" ng-disabled="!vm.validateOutfitLength()">
        <label i18n>Confirmed</label>
    </div>
</li>
```

Here is that method:

```
validateOutfitLength() 
{
    var rv = true;
    let accoms: Accommodation[] = this.quoteService.activeBasket.accommodations;

    accoms.forEach(accom => {
        if (accom.outfitLength < 350) {
            rv = false;
        }
    });
    return rv;
}
```

The error for this code is different than above! The error for this is:

> An unexpected error has occurred. TypeError: Cannot read property 'forEach' of undefined

This is a very large project that I'm working on, and I'm unaware if it's intentional that this method is being called many times... I assume it is intentional though.

Comment: Should it alert more than one message? I mean, should it generate an alert for each accomodation?

Comment: It sounds like that line of code is getting called several times, and that for all but one of them, `this.quoteService`, or `this.quoteService.activeBasket`, or `this.quoteService.activeBasket.components` is `undefined` (probably because the property hasn't been added yet). Look at where you're creating that in the lifecycle of the component. Unfortunately, we can't really help you more than that without seeing a [mcve] of the problem.

Comment: Agreed with the above statements. Could you provide a bit more of the context of your code - i.e. a few lines around this and where it's called. That way we can analyze what's happening accurately.

Comment: @hmiedema9 I have added more context, sorry about that!

Comment: @T.J.Crowder the question has been updated with slightly more context. It's a very large project, so I unfortunately don't have anything that's executable...

Comment: @Logan are you *sure* that the error is coming from that line? People read string/array lengths all over the place...

Comment: @JaredSmith Yes, I'm positive it's coming from that line, as when I remove the line the error doesn't occur.

Comment: @Logan include the stack trace in your question.

Comment: @CaseyC The `: Accommodation[]` sets the type of the variable to ensure what it's being handed is what it's expecting to hold. It's a safe practice with Typescript.

Comment: Yeah, I see that it's Typescript syntax not Javascript. OP says Javascript in the question. So fix the question to reflect that.

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
 alert(this.quoteService['activeBasket']['components'].length === undefined ? '' : this.quoteService['activeBasket']['components'].length);
```

Comment: downvoter please explain why is this way not working?

Comment: This didn't fix the issue either. I think it's because it's still trying to access the .length component, even though the object is undefined. I think if I just use an if statement to check if the 'components' object is undefined, then this should work.

Comment: if you use this method are you getting same error length not defined

Comment: Yes, it was the same error. I added an answer and gave you credit, as I wouldn't have been able to figure it out without your answer. So thanks for your help, I really appreciate it. I'm not sure who downvoted you, so I gave you an upvote for your help!

Answer (score 0):

This has been solved! I do want to give some credit to [Chellappan](https://stackoverflow.com/users/7790376/chellappan), as I wouldn't have been able to find the solution without his answer.

Basically, there must be multiple calls to the `validateOutfitLength` method and within some of those calls, the `quoteService.activeBasket.accommodations/components` were undefined. The fix was simple, it was just basically checking whether the object was undefined before doing anything with the value.

```
let accoms = this.quoteService.activeBasket.accommodations;
if (typeof(accoms) != 'undefined') {
    // do something with accoms
}
```

Comment: you are getting data from backend with little delay depend on you internet connection  speed so use setTimeout or use if condtion

Comment: @Chellappan so you're saying that's why there are multiple calls to the method, or that's why the object may be undefined originally?

Comment: check your network tab and see how frequently you getting data from backend without delay. i think multiple call due to some other reasons i am not sure